# Print the string, if string in the line ends with specific characters

Tags: python, string, file, character, line

How do I print every string that ends on 'je' in a line

For example :

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    for string in line:
        if string ends with 'je':
            print string
```

And only if the string ends with '....je' , so no 'je' included. And if the string ends with '....je?' or '....je.' remove '? , . ' . Then it should print the string. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is *"every string in a line"*?

Comment: Dat huisje daar. Dat boompje daar. Een reisje hier. Print : huisje/boompje/reisje

Comment: So, every **word** in a line?

Comment: Yeah I've got it working already but it includes 'je' aswell

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string name dosent allow '?,.' at all, it should work.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    for string in line:
        string = string.strip('.,?')
        if string.endswith('je'):
            print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code. `for string in line:` will go through every single character, not through every word. By the way, you should not name your variable `string`. `for word in line.split():` will do what you expect.

Also, `if string ends with 'je':` should be `if word.endswith('je'):`. If you don't want to match the exact word "je", you can change that to `if word.endswith('je') and word != "je":`.

Final code, including the removal of `!` and `?`:

```
f = open("a.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.rstrip("!?")
        if word.endswith('je') and word != "je":
            print(word)
```

Note that if a word ends with several `?` or `!`, they will all get removed.

Comment: Is there a way  to remove 'je'? I want it to only one with '......je' not 'je' only

Comment: I've edited my code. It now also removes `?` & `!` from the strings.